# How to decompress a custom game data file?

Tags: file-format, decompress

So here's the rundown:

The files in themselves are .spc. Normally, you'd think this is a spectrum file, but it's a custom file made by the developer themselves. It contains an image that is used/will be used in the game, and me and a group is trying to figure out how to decode it.

Here's things we've tried and know so far:

-Initially, we thought that it was a PKSC7 certificate envelope. It was not, as it was a custom file. They were unpacked from a general .cpk file, which all games in the series have utilized.

-The game in question is a PSVITA and PS4 (although our files are from the Vita version) game and is called New Danganronpa V3

-We received info from a third party that does not want to share how to decompress the files. They were the ones that taught us the SPC file is NOT a certificate or spectrum file, and that the method to decompress it was backwards and strange, and was found out mostly by accident

-We found out some strange stuff in hex files, but the most relevant information is that the .spc files are CPS., a little-endian compression method. According to some help we've found elsewhere in the internet, this is a big hint on how to decrypt said files - we've tried switching it to big-endian, but we haven't found much other than the hex data changes to be more coherent.

-Other things we've found in the hexdata include stuff like filepaths (such as a thing called "SPCpack", a few things ending in .srdi and .srd, and -BEGIN CERTIFICATE- at the top of one. Here's an image: [image: Hexdata with first three digits]

If the files themselves are needed, they are available here:

https://mega.nz/#!6xtmgBzQ!RNfIUlC94bQs4YPTVD0GuMFTi3LfqeIMrKdaxqRtCp8

Comment: As you can clearly see plain text in this dump, it is not *encrypted*, so please [edit] that out of your question for clarity. Since the plain text strings are interrupted by other codes - see `chara?_black.b?mp` -, it probably is an LZ/ARC-like derivative (bytewise, rather than the more modern bitwise, compression).